# Backbone Marionette Route Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm following Brian Mann's backbonerails.com tutorial to learn backbone/marionette. For some reason when I go to `http://localhost:3000/#users`, listUsers isn't called. Any thoughts or ideas are really appreciated!

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
@Demo.module "UsersApp", (UsersApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

class UsersApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
        "users": "listUsers"

UsersApp.API =
    listUsers: ->
        console.log "listUsers"

App.addInitializer ->
    new UsersApp.Router
        controller: UsersApp.API
```

I can also add an initializer to the UsersApp and get it to proc a console message.

```
UsersApp.addInitializer: ->
console.log("initialized UsersApp")
```

Similarly I also see a log message if I add it to

```
App.addInitializer ->
        console.log "initialized"
        new UsersApp.Router
            controller: API
```

I don't actually start Backbone routing until after the initializers are run:

```
@Demo = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

  App = new Marionette.Application

  App.addRegions
    headerRegion: "#header-region"
    mainRegion: "#main-region"
    footerRegion: "#footer-region"

  App.addInitializer ->
    App.module("HeaderApp").start()
    App.module("FooterApp").start()

  App.on "initialize:after", ->
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start()
```

App

When playing around with it it almost seems like my UsersApp.Router object isn't actually being created. Is that maybe the issue?

**EDIT**

Adding the controller as UsersApp.API seems to be getting closer:

```
App.addInitializer ->
        new UsersApp.Router
            controller: UsersApp.API
```

But now I'm getting a different error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'listUsers' of undefined
```

Why wouldn't it find the listUsers function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was that I was starting `Backbone.history` on the `"initialize:after"` event, but I really needed to be starting it on the `"start"` event:

```
App.on "start", ->
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start()
```

Doing that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `UserApp.API`. You've just defined a local variable `API` inside a function, and that variable doesn't get exposed in anyway.

If you want to use `UserApp.API`, you need to actually make `API` a property of `UserApp`.

```
@Demo.module "UsersApp", (UsersApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  UserApp.API =
    listUsers: ->
      # ...
```

Comment: Well that makes the error go away, but the console message still isn't logged. I just updated my code with the changes for readability.

Comment: @TomHammond You're logging nothing. `console.log listUsers` attempts to log a variable that isn't defined. Try `console.log "listUsers"`

Comment: Yea I caught that one right after I originally posted :)